# Why is my macro to delete rows with specific criteria not working?

Tags: excel, vba

Am I using incorrect Dim statements? The macro runs, but it does not delete anything.

Below is the coding:

```
Sub DeleteRowsonCriteria()

    Dim lastRow As Long, dataRow As Long
    Dim prodTran As String, prodTran2 As String, prodOIS As String, prodOIS2 As String
    
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    For dataRow = lastRow To 3 Step -1
    
        prodTran = Range("A" & dataRow).Text
        prodTran2 = Range("A" & dataRow).Text
        prodOIS = Range("AA" & dataRow).Text
        prodOIS2 = Range("AA" & dataRow).Text
        
        If prodTran = "Ordered" And prodTran2 = "Cancelled" And prodOIS = "Cancelled" And prodOIS2 = "Refund" Then
        
            Rows(dataRow).Delete
            
        End If
        
    Next dataRow

End Sub
```

Comment: *specifically* what happens or doesn't happen when you run your code?   Looks like you need to add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module.  That will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: OK now you've edited...   The value in Column A can't be *both* "Ordered" *and* "Cancelled"   Same goes for Column AA.

Comment: i see that it runs but it is not deleting anything.  column A in my workbook i have 3 transaction types that say "shipped, ordered, returned and cancelled" i only want to see "shipped and returned" and delete the rows that have "ordered and cancelled". after all of those are deleted there is one more column that could possibly have cancel or refund and i then want it to scan that column and delete the rows that have  "canceled or refund", the code is doing nothing

Comment: Would I have to use Or?

Comment: Yes - you should use `Or` for this.  And you don't need separate variables `prodTran2`  or `prodOIS2`

Comment: i will try tomorrow morning! and keep you posted! i was also curious i used "as integer" and it would debug and say "type mismatch" why did that happen?

Comment: Which variable(s) had you declared as Integer?

Comment: i updated formula with "or" it still didn't do anything.

Comment: At first i had the below declaring as integers but i figured since i'm not assigning a value i switched it to string. but since its not working should i do "object"

Dim prodTran As String, prodTran2 As String, prodOIS As String, prodOIS2 As String

Comment: You can try `Variant`

Comment: you mentioned i dont need to separate the variables. how do i tell it in one statement to delete "ordered & cancelled"
'

Comment: `If prodTran = "Ordered" Or prodTran = "Cancelled" Or prodOIS = "Cancelled" Or prodOIS = "Refund" Then `

Comment: i will try that. I will report tomorrow !! Appreciate all your help!

Comment: macro worked! thank you so much tim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Sub DeleteRowsonCriteria()

    Dim lastRow As Long, dataRow As Long
    Dim prodTran As String, prodOIS As String
    '===Start checking condition from Last row upwards so that when deleting it won't shift cells that are unchecked==='
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    For dataRow = lastRow To 3 Step -1  'User do not want want to delete row 1 and 2 so checking will stop at row 3, checking will start at the last row and move up (-1).
    
        prodTran = Range("A" & dataRow).Text
        prodOIS = Range("AA" & dataRow).Text
        '===As soon as any If condition is satisfied, it will delete the row and go straight to "End if" section, otherwise it will check the next "ElseIF" condition below it and do the same===".
        If prodTran = "Ordered" Then
           Rows(dataRow).Delete    
          
            ElseIf prodTran = "Cancelled" Then
            Rows(dataRow).Delete
            
            ElseIf prodOIS = "Cancelled" Then
            Rows(dataRow).Delete
            
            ElseIf prodOIS = "Refund" Then
            Rows(dataRow).Delete
            
        End If
        
    Next dataRow  'This is for the checking the next row moving up (Looping) .

End Sub
```